# How to pass null value in gherkin DataTable?

Tags: java, null, cucumber, gherkin

Is there any way to pass null value to gherkin DataTable? When I pass empty value to "examples" in scenario outline it returns me empty string ("") in request body, But when I pass empty value to DataTable it ignore that field at all. I also tried to pass "null" in DataTable, but it returns null as a string not data type. In Postman I'm able to pass null and it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried with an ASCII null ? By its nature it is hard to represent null values in text.

Answer (score 0):

The below is printing empty string

```
Scenario:  login registration using cucumber data table
      When I submit login details
       |Username     |"angular2"|
        |Password    |"password2"|
        |UsernameDesc | "        "|
```

stepdef:

```
        @When ("^I submit login details$")
 public void submitLoginDetails(DataTable dataTable ){
    List<loginDetails> list = dataTable.transpose().asList(loginDetails.class);
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    for (loginDetails l : list) {
        System.out.println("username::"+l.getUserName());
        System.out.println("pwd::"+l.getPassword());
        System.out.println("usernamedesc::"+l.getUsernameDesc());
    }
```

loginDetails class

```
public class loginDetails {
    
    private String Username;
    private String Password;
    private String UsernameDesc;
    
    public  loginDetails(String uname, String pwd, String udesc){
        this.Username=uname;
        this.Password = pwd;
        this.UsernameDesc = udesc;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return Username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }
    public String getUsernameDesc() {
        return UsernameDesc;
    }
}
```

I get output

```
       username::
[DEBUG] "angular2"
[DEBUG] pwd::
[DEBUG] "password2"
[DEBUG] usernamedesc::
[DEBUG] "        "
```

Alternatively, if you would like to convert "null" to null using `@ParameterType` use below

```
Scenario: transformation tests
    
   Given someOtherThing has a value null
```

stepdefs

```
@Given("someOtherThing has a value {ConvertToNull}")
public void checkNull(Boolean b){
assertThat(b).isEqualTo(null);  //this test passed
}

@ParameterType(".*?")
 //you can only use reference types as method return type to return null. 
 //primitives will not work
public Boolean ConvertToNull(String v) {  
if(v.equals("null")){
          return null;
 }  
    }
```